# CSS Not showing up in my HTML, using CSS3 In Photoshop

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make CSS3 in Photoshop, using a plugin.
And Everything shows up fine in [CSS3 Preview](http://css3.ps/?=411a8f44-e78e-aeb4-a022-529a14cc77c4)
in my Browser, it doesn't show up anything!!!

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<html>
<head> 
    <html></html>
<style type="text/css">
          .button1{
{
    width: 337px;
    height: 191px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #dd2626;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(19,2,2,.97), inset 0 0 7px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(19,2,2,.97), inset 0 0 7px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(19,2,2,.97), inset 0 0 7px #fff;
    border: solid 6px #000;
}
          }

        </style>

</head>



<body>

    <div class="button1">
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that button is massive! Do you still need the prefixes?? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra `{`. Use a [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

```
          .button1{
{
```

Comment: @j08691 — True. That one won't actually cause a problem those as error recovery will handle it (which isn't to say it shouldn't be removed).

Comment: browser dependant maybe, It shown nothin for me with the extra brackets